# Cytoscape.js HTML links in label not clickable with expand-collapse expansion

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am trying to setup a cytoscape.js graph, which includes links in node labels and also expandable/collapsable parent nodes. After some research I decided to use the `cytoscape-node-html-label` extension in combination with the `expand-collapse` extension.

I played around with both extensions separately and they do what I want. However, when trying to combine them, HTML links are not clickable any more. It seems like the expand/collapse extension adds a layer, which does not propagate mouse events to the HTML extension.

```
{
        enablePointerEvents: true
    }
```

is already set for the HTML label extension but does not solve the problem. Please find a minimum working example below.

I am happy to get your support on

- how to propagate clicks to the HTML label or
- how to move the HTML labels "on top" of the expand/collapse layer.

Thank you in advance :-)

**code.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
        layout: {
            name: 'fcose'
        },

        elements: {
            nodes: [
                { data: { id: 'node1', type: 2 } },
                { data: { id: 'node1.1', parent: 'node1' } },
                { data: { id: 'node2' } },
            ],
            edges: [
                { data: { source: 'node1', target: 'node2' } },
            ]
        },
    });

    cy.nodeHtmlLabel([{
        query: 'node[type=2]',
        valign: "top",
        valignBox: "top",
        tpl: function() {
            return '<p>Test label 1. <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link</a></p>'
        }
    }], {
        enablePointerEvents: true
    });

    // If the following block is commented, the HTML link above works
    var api = cy.expandCollapse({
        layoutBy: {
            name: "fcose",
            animate: true,
            randomize: false,
            fit: true
        },
        fisheye: true,
        animate: true,
        undoable: false,
    });

});
```

**demo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
    <title>cytoscape-expand-collapse.js demo</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

    <!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
    <!--<script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/layout-base/layout-base.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cose-base/cose-base.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-fcose/cytoscape-fcose.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-expand-collapse/cytoscape-expand-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="src/cytoscape-node-html-label.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>cytoscape-expand-collapse demo</h1>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <div style="float: right; height: 95%; width: calc(80% - 4px);" id="cy"></div>

</body>

</html>
```